# How to show help text on hover in lightning component?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, helptext, force

I have used `force:recordView` to display the record detail in lightning component.I am not getting help text option over there.
Do I need to do some additional work for that.I have confirmed through this [Idea](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000LhEHAA0)
 that it possible now.

Comment: Have you defined help text in the field information section? Look under Setup--> object manager --> object --> fields and relationship --> fields --> field formation section --> see if you have a help text for the field

Comment: @Rao Yes, There is help text for the field, also it is visible in salesforce classic but not in lightning custom component (force:recordView) .